# Not the usual WordPress 'NOT EXISTS' meta query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've encountered an issue where "not exists" meta queries do not work as expected if there are **no metadata at all** on the particular post. Something like...

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts' , 'my_pre_get_posts' );
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'mymetakey', 
                'value' => '', 
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'mymetakey',
                'value' => '1', 
                'compare' => '!='
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

This works fine, as expected, when the post has *some* metadata.. any other metadata. Just hitting the editor fixes this because of the '_edit_lock' meta. However the autogenerated woocommerce pages do not have this, and out of the box - this query does not work.

Presumably this is an idiosyncrasy of the way the table joins work. Anybody know a good workaround - other than writing some dummy meta data into each post.

Comment: What version of WP are you using?

Comment: This was seen on 4.0. I've seen there are meta query enhancements in 4.1, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Here's a [similar question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168336/compare-meta-query-in-get-posts-arguments). The reason I asked for the version is the following note in the Codex: "Due to bug #23268, value is required for NOT EXISTS comparisons to work correctly prior to 3.9. You must supply some string for the value parameter. An empty string or NULL will NOT work. However, any other string will do the trick and will NOT show up in your SQL when using NOT EXISTS. Need inspiration? How about 'bug #23268'."

Comment: Yes - that is the question which I found loads of answers for. Empty strings work fine on the 'Not EXISTS'. This appears to be fixed in the recently released WordPress 4.1 (yey)

Comment: glad to hear it's resolved ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem goes away upon upgrading to WordPress 4.1. I should've waited 1 day for the release!